# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT if value is not a substring

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a column called "Permissions" in my table. The permissions are strings which can be:
`"r","w","x","rw","wx","rwx","xwr"`
etc. Please note the order of characters in the string is not fixed. I want to `GROUP_CONCAT()` on the "Permissions" column of my table. However this causes very large strings.

Example: `"r","wr","wx"` group concatenated is `"r,wr,wx"`  but should be `"r,w,x"` or `"rwx"`. Using `distinct()` clause doesn't seem to help much. I am thinking that if I could check if a permission value is a substring of the other column then I should not concatenate it, but I don't seem to find a way to accomplish that.

Any column based approach using solely string functions would also be appreicated.

EDIT:
Here is some sample data:

```
+---------+
| perm    |
+---------+
| r,x,x,r |
| x       |
| w,rw    |
| rw      |
| rw      |
| x       |
| w       |
| x,x,r   |
| r,x     |
+---------+
```

The concatenated result should be:

```
 +---------+
 | perm    |
 +---------+
 | r,w,x   |
 +---------+
```

I don't have control over the source of data and would like not to create new tables ( because of restricted privileges and memory constraints). I am looking for a post-processing step that converts each column value to the desired format.

Comment: Hint: think about SETs, not text strings, here.

Comment: maybe a few lines of your sample data and expected result will help people understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be to first *normalize* your data.

You could, for example try this way (I assume your source table is named `Files`):

1. Create simple table called `PermissionCodes` with only column named `Code` (type of string).
2. Put `r`, `w`, and `x` as values into `PermissionCodes` (three rows total).
3. In a subquery join `Files` to `PermissionCodes` on a condition that `Code` exists as a substring in `Permissions`.
4. Perform your `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation on the result of the subquery.

If it is a case here, that for the same logical entires in `Files` there exists multiple permission sets that overlaps (i.e. for some file there is a row with `rw` and another row with `w`) then you would limit your subquery to *distinct* combinations of `Files`' keys and `Code`.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the idea:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6685d6/4

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT perm)
FROM Permissions AS p
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'r' AS perm UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'w' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'x') AS x
ON p.permission LIKE CONCAT('%', x.perm, '%')
GROUP BY user_id
```

You can include any additional permission code in the `UNION ALL` of the derived table used to `JOIN` with `Permissions` table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e6ac/6)

Comment: Similar to Kuba's solution. Much appreciated help. Thanks.